# How to display javascript average result in bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this javascript code that return to me result in alert window

```
$(".average").click(function () {
    alert(average())
});
```

But, now i want to display that result in bootstrap modal window. How can i show result in modal? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [the example from the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) of the Bootstrap modal, you simply need to insert the result of your average function into the modal body and then show the modal. Assuming your modal has an id of `#myModal`:

```
$(".average").click(function () {
  var result = average();
  $("#myModal .modal-body p").text(result);
  $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Look at the documentation, link above, for more info on the Boostrap modal, and what options you pass to it.